# Balloon tool tip is crashing the application

Tags: c#

As soon as the Balloon Tool tip pops up the application gets crashed. This scenario is observed only when the application is running in Windows 8 PC.

Here is the code which we are calling

```
public void BalloonInfo(Control aControl, string aText, BalloonAlignment aAlignment, int aDuration)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (m_mb.IsVisible) return;
                //HideHint();
                m_mb = new MessageBalloon();
                m_mb.Parent = aControl;
                m_mb.Title = "Information";
                m_mb.TitleIcon = TooltipIcon.Info;
                m_mb.Text = aText;
                m_mb.Align = aAlignment;
                m_mb.CenterStem = false;
                m_mb.UseAbsolutePositioning = false;
                m_mb.Show();
                EnableTimer(true, aDuration);
            }
        }
```

Is there any relation that WIN 32 handlers won't work with Windows8.

Comment: What is the type of CPU of the computer?

Comment: What is `EnableTimer()` doing (code would be in order here)? What do you mean be "crashing"? Do you have an exception stacktrace?

Comment: `lock(this)` looks dodgy. And what does the debugger say when it crashes?